# mathematical operators in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mathematical-expressions

is it possible to use mathematical operators in .htaccess file?
for example i want to redirect a page with id=100 to a page with id=30 ?

Comment: What part is a mathematical expression?  Mapping a query string where id=100 to a query string with id=30 as @bradym answered is simple pattern matching and substitution.  A mathematical expression would be mapping a query string where id=X to a query string with id=(X-70) for all X in the range of 100 to 1000.

Comment: no,id will have different values,between 1 to n .that is why i said mathematical expression.

Comment: Can you post an example of your use of RewriteMap?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about query strings, yes.

To redirect `http://example.com/page.php?id=100` to `http://example.com/page.php?id=30` you would do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=100
RewriteRule page.php page.php?id=30 [R=301,L]
```

**Edit:** AFAIK, it's not possible to do calculations in .htaccess. Send the request to a PHP script where you do the calculation then use the [header](http://php.net/header) function to do the redirect (not sure if you're using PHP, but the same principle applies to other languages).

in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule page.php calc.php?id=%1 [L]
```

And in calc.php:

```
<?php    
$base_url = 'http://example.com/destination.php?id=';

if($_GET['id'] < 100){
    $new_id = 30;
}
elseif($_GET['id'] >= 100){
    $new_id = 40;
}

$url = $base_url.$new_id;

header("Location: $url"); 
exit();
```

Comment: id has different values,not only 100 .